# How to deploy JupyterHub using Nginx?

Tags: proxy, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, jupyterhub, ubuntu-17.10

I'm seriously stuck here. Definitely tech savvy, not a sys admin. [Here is what I've done so far to deploy JupyterHub on Azure](https://github.com/SeaDude/azure-jupyterhub/blob/testing/jupyterLabInstall.md).
Overview:

- Create self-signed ssl cert using Azure keyvault
- Deploy Ubuntu Server 17.10 VM on Azure
- Install Anaconda in `/opt/anaconda/anaconda4`
- Install Jupyterhub via conda

Here I am stuck. When running `jupyterhub` as root, I get: 
 - `JupyterHub is now running at http://:8000/`.

When running `jupyterhub --ip my.ip.address --port 443 --ssl-key /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.prv --ssl-cert /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.cert` as root, I get: 
 - `JupyterHub is now running at https://my.ip.address:443/

Neither of which result in the jupyterhub UI. Just says "Welcome to nginx". I'm not sure where to go. Any advice is appreciate.